# return confimation writing "ok"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

How can I make a user write something on a confirmation

Ex.
I'm trying to make an alert saying "Are you sure you want to delete this name?"

and then then user will need to write

"sure" or "okay"

This is what im using now.

```
<a href="deleteCourse.php">"onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this name?');" class="deleteColor">Delete</a>
```

Comment: use [propmpt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.prompt)

Comment: Another option would be to show a jquery ui dialog instead. Then you can design it however you would like. http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to Ran Charam

```
else  
  event.preventDefault();
```

This is how you link should look

```
<a href="deleteCourse.php">"onclick="confirmDelete()" class="deleteColor">Delete</a>
```

and this is the .js

```
function confirmDelete() {
    var response = prompt("Please type [DELETE] to confirm you want to delete this entry");

    if (response=='DELETE') {
        return true;
    }
    else  
        event.preventDefault();


}
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you want to use a prompt:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_prompt.asp

Maybe write something like:

```
function confirmDelete() {
    var response = prompt("Please type [DELETE] to confirm you want to delete this entry", "Confirm Delete");

    if (response=='DELETE') {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: If the user don't write the correct word(DELETE) how can prevent the page

Answer (score -3):

Unfortunately this outside of our control. Instead you will have to create your own modal window with a text field.

See jquery-ui for some examples on this.